# How to make ng-repeat work with a function returning a new object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my HTML, I have the following element:

```
<button ng-click="console.log(key)" ng-repeat="(key, value) in getLsKeys() track by $index">
```

and in my JS I have:

```
$scope.getLsKeys = function(){
    return localStorageService.get('accountKeys');
};
```

The Local Storage value can be seen here: http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/daf62c

No matter what I do, I always get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.
Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 121; oldVal: 118"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 124; oldVal: 121"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 127; oldVal: 124"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 130; oldVal: 127"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 133; oldVal: 130"]]
```

I understand that ng-repeat tries to match the exact object, which will be different every time and getLsKeys creates and returns a new object. What I do not understand is why "track by $index" does not fix this problem; to my understanding, track by was implemented to solve this specific problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should first transform your object in an array, for instance

```
var arr = [];
var obj = localStorageService.get('accountKeys');
for (var i in obj) {
  var item = obj[i];
  item.id = i;
  arr.push(item);
}
```

Then you bind ng-repeat to this array, and to avoid infinite redigestion you track the element according to a unique identifier (for instance what I've called `id` here, that contains the different email address)

```
<button ng-click="console.log(key)" ng-repeat="item in getLsKeys() track by item.id">
```

NOTE: it would be more performant to do the object to array transformation outside of the `getLsKeys` if possible, so that it is not done again on every digest cycle.

Comment: Do you know why my current code does not work? "Track by" is definitely supported with "(key, value)" expressions to some degree, as substituting "undefinedProperty" for "$index" gets a duplicate item error for the ngRepeat (as all items are seen to be the same, as they are all identified by "undefined").

Comment: Also, I am unsure if the JS you wrote down was intended to be the new function body for getLsKeys, but if it was (assuming as well that you add a return arr line), the code still does not work. It generates the same duplicate key error as writing in "track by undefinedValue".

I am also aware that if I define $scope.arr outside the function body, update it with getLsKeys(), and ngRepeat over $scope.arr directly, that it will work "correctly", but that is undesired.

Comment: well I intentionnaly didn't specify because it would better be out of the function. But if it is (at least as proof of concept) be sure to return `arr` at the end of the function. Track by work on object to some extent, but I don't know more about it and wouldn't recommend it anyway. Maybe worth trying `track by key`?